# Button Soft Delete Not Functioning laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

i'm using laravel 8 to make a function softdeletes. In my view pages, my button is not working and there is no error just not functioning. i'm not sure if this unfunctioning is from the migration or the controller.

So here is my migration

```
public function up()
{
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id();
 $table->string('name');
 $table->string('detail');
 $table->timestamps();
 $table->softDeletes();
});
}
```

My product model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $fillable = [
'name',
'detail'
];
}
```

my product controller

```
public function delete($id)
{
$product = Product::where('id',$id) -> first();
$products = Product::all();

if ($product != null) {
$product->withTrashed()->get();
return redirect()->route('pro.index')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);

}
return view('products.pro_index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/delete-index/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'delete'])->name('delete');
```

My view button

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('delete', $product->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

Will very appreciate if someone willing to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never deleting the product in your controller.

You have to call the `delete()` method:

```php
public function delete($id)
{
   $product = Product::where('id',$id) -> first();
   $products = Product::all();

   if ($product != null) {
      //$product->withTrashed()->get(); useless here
      $product->delete(); // will soft delete the product
      //$product->forceDelete(); // will hard delete the product
      return redirect()->route('pro.index')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
   }
   return view('products.pro_index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Please note that you are deleting your product after getting all the products (`$products = Product::all();` is before `$product->delete();`), so you'll probably need to refresh your page again to actually see the product deleted.

Aside your question, you also should:

- delete your product inside a `DELETE` request, not `GET`
- redirect to the index route with `return redirect()->route('your_route_name');` (it'll also solve the problem mentioned above about deleting the product after `Product::all()`)

Comment: Glad to see it works :) I've updated my answer with some improvments regarding your code. I see you are new to SO, don't forget to validate the answer so other people with the same issue can easily solve their problem. Have a good day!

Comment: It works if you first find the element, then run delete() on it: $product = Product::find($id); $product->delete();